Laravel MongoDB - Session driver
I'm currently trying to upgrade my Laravel 8 app to Laravel 11. With Laravel 8 I used the old jenssegers/laravel-mongodb + jenssegers/laravel-mongodb-session package for storing user sessions in the database. For Laravel 11 I have to use the new mongodb/laravel-mongodb package. There don't seem  to be a separate package for storing the session in the database.
.env file
# this worked for the old 
# jenssegers/laravel-mongodb-session package.
# Now I get "Driver [mongodb] not supported"

#SESSION_DRIVER=mongodb


# not working, I get "Session expired" after login
#SESSION_DRIVER=database 


SESSION_DRIVER=file # my current workaround
SESSION_DOMAIN=my.domain
SESSION_COOKIE=myapp_cookie

Connection to MongoDB works fine.
How do I store the session in the database with the new mongodb/laravel-mongodb package?

From the documentation (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/php/laravel-mongodb/current/)

This documentation describes the mongodb/laravel-mongodb package, formerly named jenssegers/mongodb. This package is now owned and maintained by MongoDB, Inc. and is compatible with Laravel 10.x and later.

It's the same package. I think you can get away with continuing to use laravel-mongodb-session

No, it does not work with Laravel >= 9. A MongoDB session driver for Laravel 4, 5, 6, 7 or 8  from https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb-session

You're right. Then unfortunately the alternative is that you simply implement that package inside your project in a way that it is compatible with laravel 11 (look at the upgrade guides for help) or create a fork and instruct composer to get the package from your repository instead of the original source.

Fortunately, it's not a very big package so it shouldn't be too painful. Jenssegers\Mongodb\Session\SessionManager is very small; and Jenssegers\Mongodb\Session\SessionServiceProvider is even smaller. And that's the whole package.

You can keep using the mongodb/laravel-mongodb extension and solve this error by creating a Custom Session Handler in
/app/Extensions/MongoSessionHandler.php

with the below code:
<?php

namespace App\Extensions;

use MongoDB\Client;
use SessionHandlerInterface;

class MongoSessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface
{
    protected $collection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $client = new Client(env('MONGODB_URI'));
        $this->collection = $client->selectCollection(env('DB_DATABASE'), 'sessions');
    }

    public function open($savePath, $sessionName)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function close()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function read($sessionId)
    {
        $session = $this->collection->findOne(['_id' => $sessionId]);
        return $session ? $session['data'] : '';
    }

    public function write($sessionId, $data)
    {
        $this->collection->updateOne(
            ['_id' => $sessionId],
            ['$set' => ['data' => $data, 'last_accessed' => new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime()]],
            ['upsert' => true]
        );
        return true;
    }

    public function destroy($sessionId)
    {
        $this->collection->deleteOne(['_id' => $sessionId]);
        return true;
    }

    public function gc($maxLifetime)
    {
        $past = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime((time() - $maxLifetime) * 1000);
        $this->collection->deleteMany(['last_accessed' => ['$lt' => $past]]);
        return true;
    }
}

and registering it in
/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

as follows
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Extensions\MongoSessionHandler;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        $this->app['session']->extend('mongodb', function ($app) {
            return new MongoSessionHandler();
        });
    }

}

for .env
DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=27017
DB_DATABASE=SIH-2024
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=

SESSION_DRIVER=mongodb
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_ENCRYPT=false
SESSION_PATH=/
SESSION_DOMAIN=null

This way, if a session already exists with the same ID, it will be updated; if it doesn't exist, it will be inserted.
